# React Native - react-native-camera error building on Android

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I've been struggling with this all day.
I did the same thing that the [repo](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera) says.

I ran:

> `npm install react-native-camera --save`
>
> `react-native link react-native-camera`

The output said that everything was linked correctly.
But when I do:

> `react-native run-android`

I get this error:

> `\MainApplication.java:6: error: package org.reactnative.camera does
>   not exist import org.reactnative.camera.RNCameraPackage;
>                                          ^`
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

That's not the entire error, I think that's just the most relevant part of it.

Any hand?

Comment: Did you try to install it manually for android???

Comment: Yes, I get this error: `Execution failed for task ':react-native-camera:processReleaseResources'.
> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms.license' `

Answer (score 0):

Insert the following lines inside the dependencies block in android/app/build.gradle:

```
compile (project(':react-native-camera')) {
    exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
    compile 'com.android.support:exifinterface:25.+'
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:12.0.1') {
        force = true
    }
}
```

*You may need to use different exifinterface versions, e.g. 27.+ instead of 25.+.*

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera

4th step on manual installation on android.